# Install Alamofire in Xcode 9 Swift 3 Watch app

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I have followed the [installation instructions](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire#installation) but am getting the following error when opening my project's xcworkspace in Xcode 9.2

> The target “Alamofire” contains source code developed with Swift 2.x. Xcode 9 does not support building or migrating Swift 2.x targets.
>   Use Xcode 8.x to migrate the code to Swift 3.

Not sure if I have an old version of Alamofire: my Podfile contains

> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
>   platform :ios, '9.0'
>   use_frameworks!
>   target 'raceQs' do
>   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
>   pod 'DLAlertView'
>   pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
>   pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK'
>   pod 'SWRevealViewController'
>   pod 'SSKeychain'
>   pod 'SSZipArchive'
>   pod 'mailcore2-ios'
>   pod 'CrashlyticsFramework'
>   end

pod install reported

> Installing Alamofire (4.6.0)

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass the Alamofire version. Make the following changes to your podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'raceQs' do
  pod 'Alamofire'
  //rest of your pods
end
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't fix the problem.
It still installs  Alamofire (4.6.0) and Xcode still reports:
The target “Alamofire” contains source code developed with Swift 2.x. Xcode 9 does not support building or migrating Swift 2.x targets.

Use Xcode 8.x to migrate the code to Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing as the advice instructed. I downloaded Xcode 8.3.3 from the [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) loaded my project (which of course generated '000s of errors) and followed the prompts to upgrade to Swift 3. Then closed 8.3.3, and opened my project in Xcode 9.2 - sweet!
Just 1/2 hour of my life I won't get back.

OOPS.. I spoke too early.... Althugh the project now opens in Xcode 9, when I add import Alamofire into my Swift module  in my watchkit Extension I get "No such module Alamofire"

Comment: @StrarTraX are you still facing the same problem. I am having it as well and i tried almost everything and nothing seems to work

Comment: See my answer below. Please report success or failure!

Answer (score 0):

I never succeeded by using Pods.
However, I have got it working using the "other" method.
First, I downloaded Alamofire and copied to my Project folder:
[image: My app is raceqs and I have copied the Alamofire projects to the raceqs project folder:]

Then, I imported Alamofire.xcode into my project in Xcode:
[image]

Then I updated my Embedded Binaries and Linked Frameworks with Alamofire.framework:
[image]

There is some weird issue with Xcode, that causes it to take a while - 5 minutes or so, before it recognises import Alamofire in my Swift code file.